# Other than foo++, is there any other way to have a variable change value after it is evaluated in one statement?

Tags: java

Let's say I want to write a one time gate that looks like this...

```
int closing = 1;
if(closing-- > 0){
   //this will only work once
}
```

I'm curious if there are any other mechanism that work this way (or can be made to) so that I could potentially overload an operator (so to speak) to behave similarly with Objects.

I have a feeling this is not doable, but I'd be very curious to find out how, if I'm wrong.

Sample "wish" code...

```
class MagicObject{
   public String oldVal = "apple"
   public String magicPostEvalString(String newVal){
      return oldVal;
      oldVal = newVal;
   }
}

MagicObject mo = new MagicObject();

if(mo.magicPostEval("orange").equals("apple"))
//this will also only happen once
```

Notice that in my magicPostEvalString, the value is being set after the return so that it returns the old value prior to modifying it.

In essence this is what foo++ is doing... it evaluates and then changes the value.

Comment: write some code that you *wished* would work so we understand what you want

Comment: If that variable is member of some class, some other thread could change it. I don't understand exactly your question, please explain more and give additional context.

Comment: Java does not allow operator overloading... If you meant that in a literal way.

Comment: @CPUTerminator, I don't mean it in the literal way, hence the "so to speak" parenthetical. Bohemian... (goofy) sample wish code added.

Comment: For the record, your initial example doesn't account for underflow. given enough executions, it *will* execute your commented section again, just not immediately.

Comment: @Mac, yes... I recognize that. Let's assume the code is being executed just a few times (or a few million times :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
public String magicPostEvalString(String newVal){
      return oldVal;
      oldVal = newVal;
}
```

You can do this to overwrite oldval and also return oldval:

```
public String magicPostEvalString(String newVal){
      String tmp = oldval;
      oldVal = newVal;
      return tmp;
}
```

Something similar is done in `java.util.Map#put(key, val)` method as well.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if that's how -- and ++ work, beneath the hood.  Ok... I'll accept that as the right answer. :)

Comment: Not sure about `++` and `--` but I believe `java.util.Map#put(key, val)` certainly works this way.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an operator but it's easy to do this by modifying the function in MagicObject.

```
class MagicObject{
    public String oldVal = "apple"
    public String magicPostEvalString(String newVal){
        String temp = oldVal;
        oldVal = newVal;
        return temp;
    }
}
```